# Is there a way to hide YouTube controls completely while in full screen?

Tags: firefox, youtube, stylish

So I'm wondering if there is a way for me to disable the YouTube controls, seekbar, and title (watch later) overlay buttons.

I use the YouTube keyboard shortcuts all the time and when I see the top and bottom overlay slide in, it irritates the crap out of me as it hides useful info behind the semi transparent bars.

I'm using Firefox with *Stylish* installed but can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you set YouTube to always use the HTML5 player** (a good idea anyway), then you can hide the controls using Stylish.
This does the trick:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("www.youtube.com") {
    .ytp-chrome-bottom, .ytp-chrome-top {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

But **be warned:**

1. It's *probably* not possible to hide the Flash player controls. (Don't use Flash anyway.)
2. Using Stylish like this hides the controls at all times -- which I find just as annoying as the controls flashing up at unwanted times.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I wanted. I set the top to disable, and the bottom part as full transparent until I hover over it then full opacity.

Comment: I believe stylish is no longer recommended due to privacy concerns. Maybe a userscript would be safer not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I implement this in chrome, and this method should work in firefox.

Firstly, install an ad blocker extenstion like [AdBlocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblocker-ultimate/ohahllgiabjaoigichmmfljhkcfikeof).

Secondly, open extenstion options interface and add following code snippet to your own filter:

```
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-gradient-top
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-top
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-gradient-bottom
```

Then it wiil work.

An image descrip this:
[image: block title when full screen]

---

How to find that filter, it also is easy, open your target website and click F12 key, do this first :
[image: find filter]

Then construct a formula defined by AdBlocker:

```
(Website's Host)##(The selector)
```

and here is:

```
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom
```

It should be noted that you need set the video full screen to find the selector when you want to block the title in full screen mode.

(There may be a grammatical error, but I don’t think it will affect your understanding.)

Answer (score 2):

It worked after adding these in Ublock Origin Filters:

```
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-gradient-top
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-top
youtube.com###movie_player > div.ytp-gradient-bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is:

- Go to 'share' then click 'embed';
- You get a video preview and just uncheck the relevant options below.

Answer (score 0):

Need [`Stylus`](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/).

In fullscreen, controls will be hidden unless mouse over the botton area.

```css
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-chrome-top,
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-gradient-top,
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-gradient-bottom {
    display: none !important;
}
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-caption-window-container > .caption-window.ytp-caption-window-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-chrome-bottom:hover {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen > .ytp-chrome-bottom:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```